# Change Certificate order in Keystore

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, keystore, truststore

I have 2 certificates, each of chain length 3 in my keystore, one for my own application and one to connect to a third party. These 2 different certificates are also present in the keystore.jks file in the elasticsearch keystore directory.So the issue I'm facing is that my elasticsearch is picking up the wrong certificate from the keystore.jks file.It's picking up the certificate which is mentioned at the end in my keystore.jks file.I somehow need to change the order of the certificates in my keystore.jks but I'm failing to do so.

1. What is the criteria for the order of the certificates in the keystore.jks file?
2. What can be done to change the order ?I tried renaming the alias in both alphabetical orders but the order didn't change,even tried deleting and importing it again.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved after renaming the alias to something else

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the default `KeyStore` implementation (`JavaKeyStore`), provided by the JDK, uses a `Hashtable` to store the entries. Thus the ordering, although consistent for a given JDK version, cannot be relied on and might well change when switching to a different JDK. (I was looking at JDK 1.8 here).

Ideally your application or library should have a way to use a specific alias from a keystore.